# Use toLocalString and Reduce Function Together : toLocaleString shows NaN in display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on internationalization and currently i have a function as:

```
getDisputedAmount() {
return this.compactInvoices.reduce((sum, invoice) => {
  const result = sum + parseFloat(invoice.disputedAmount || 0);
  return result;
}, 0);
```

}

Now i am bringing country locale and country code using service and using the .toLocaleString like this:

```
getDisputedAmount() {
return this.compactInvoices.reduce((sum, invoice) => {
  const result = sum + parseFloat(invoice.disputedAmount || 0);
  const currencyLocale = this.UserPreferences.getCountryLocale(); //for eg --> 'de-DE'
  const currencyCode = this.UserPreferences.getCountryCode(); // 'EUR'
  return Number(result).toLocaleString(currencyLocale, {
  // style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
}, 0);
```

}

But somehow using the first function brings back the right result, but if i use toLocaleString, it brings NaN in the UI. I have checked the values in the sources tab and the latter code with toLocaleString is having the correct numbers.

Also i am calling the function in the html using interpolation

```
<div class="col-140"><span class="sum-label">{{ modal.getDisputedAmount() }}</span></div>
```

If i apply Number pipe there, i even do not see the NaN written at GUI, its just blank.

Let me know your suggestions.

The values in the compactInvoices is number, i think when the toLocaleString runs for the first time, the sum is converted to a string currency format and while adding sum(which is string) to the new disputedAmount in the reduce function itself gives a NaN. 
So please share how to use toLocalString and reduce function together.

Comment: according to your code, `this.compactInvoices` does not always contain Float numbers, you should check how it is filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the formatting *after* calculating the sum with `reduce`.

```
getDisputedAmount() {
  const result = this.compactInvoices.reduce((sum, invoice) => {
    return sum + (parseFloat(invoice.disputedAmount) || 0);
  }, 0);
  const currencyLocale = this.UserPreferences.getCountryLocale(); //for eg --> 'de-DE'
  const currencyCode = this.UserPreferences.getCountryCode(); // 'EUR'
  return result.toLocaleString(currencyLocale, {
    // style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
}
```